# How to remove window borders in Smart GWT

Tags: window, smartgwt

I am using Smart GWT 3.1. The window has no title. Therefore it leaves uneven borders. How can I get rid of the borders? Or make all size borders even?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

The following lines will solve your problem:

```
setShowHeader(false);
setShowStatusBar(false);
setLayoutMargin(0); // to remove 4px gray border
setAttribute("styleName", "", true); // to remove 1px (rounded) outer border
setBodyStyle(""); // to remove 1px body border
setBodyColor(null); // to make background transparent
```

Have a nice day ;-)